# Unable to login to SQL Server + SQL Server Authentication

Tags: sql-server-2005

i forget my sql server username and password(sql server 2005).therfore i didn't get into sql server.So please give some answers to me.how can i solve this problem?

Comment: a quick google should suffice. Also, off-topic.

Comment: oh look!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196150/is-there-a-way-i-can-retrieve-sa-password-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1):

Run Sql Server locally with -m and -f flags and login to it as local admin

**OR**

login as domain administrator